# running beautiful soup on brower opened using selenium(geckodriver)

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup

currently, I am trying to **scrape** a website which generates captcha as text in the source. I want to automate the process of filling the form on that website using selenium. But every time I **scrape** the website the captcha for selenium webpage and **scraped** webpage become different, can someone help we out on this?
website: https://webkiosk.jiit.ac.in

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
results=requests.get("https://webkiosk.jiit.ac.in/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(src,'html5lib')
links=soup.find_all("td");
#finding the captcha from link text
for i in links:
    if(i.text.find("Parents")):
        f=1;
    if(f and i.text!='*' and i.text!='' and len(i.text)==5):
        p=(i.text)
        break
#captcha is getting stored in variable p
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://webkiosk.jiit.ac.in/")
driver.find_element_by_name("MemberCode").send_keys('*****')
driver.find_element_by_name("DATE1").send_keys('******')
driver.find_element_by_name("Password101117").send_keys('#******')
driver.find_element_by_name("txtcap").send_keys(p)
#driver.find_element_by_name("BTNSubmit").click()
```

Comment: What are your _Manual Steps_? If you are trying to login, why do you need _Beautiful Soup_?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am using beautiful soup for scrapping the website to pick up the captcha.